# Convert different units of a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a Kaggle project. Below is my CSV file column:

```
total_sqft
1056
1112
34.46Sq. Meter
4125Perch
1015 - 1540
34.46
10Sq. Yards
10Acres
10Guntha
10Grounds
```

The column is of type object. First I want to convert all the values to float then update the string `1015 - 1540` with its average value and finally convert the units to square feet. I've tried different StackOverflow solutions but none of them seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Expected Output:

```
total_sqft
1056.00
1112.00
370.307
1123031.25
1277.5
34.46
90.00
435600
10890
24003.5

1 square meter = 10.764 * square foot
1 perch = 272.25 * square foot 
1 square yards = 9 * square foot   
1 acres = 43560 * square foot
1 guntha = 1089 * square foot
1 grounds = 2400.35 * square foot
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: answer was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First extract numeric values by [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), convert to floats and get averages:

```
df['avg'] = (df['total_sqft'].str.extractall(r'(\d+\.*\d*)')
                             .astype(float)
                             .groupby(level=0)
                             .mean())
print (df)
       total_sqft      avg
0            1056  1056.00
1            1112  1112.00
2  34.46Sq. Meter    34.46
3       4125Perch  4125.00
4     1015 - 1540  1277.50
5           34.46    34.46
```

then need more information for convert to `square feet`.

EDIT: Create dictionary for match units, extract them from column and use `map`, last multiple columns:

```
d = {'Sq. Meter': 10.764, 'Perch':272.25, 'Sq. Yards':9,
     'Acres':43560,'Guntha':1089,'Grounds':2400.35}

df['avg'] = (df['total_sqft'].str.extractall(r'(\d+\.*\d*)')
                             .astype(float)
                             .groupby(level=0)
                             .mean())

df['unit'] = df['total_sqft'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(d)})', expand=False)

df['map'] = df['unit'].map(d).fillna(1)

df['total_sqft'] = df['avg'].mul(df['map'])
print (df)
     total_sqft      avg       unit        map
0  1.056000e+03  1056.00        NaN      1.000
1  1.112000e+03  1112.00        NaN      1.000
2  3.709274e+02    34.46  Sq. Meter     10.764
3  1.123031e+06  4125.00      Perch    272.250
4  1.277500e+03  1277.50        NaN      1.000
5  3.446000e+01    34.46        NaN      1.000
6  9.000000e+01    10.00  Sq. Yards      9.000
7  4.356000e+05    10.00      Acres  43560.000
8  1.089000e+04    10.00     Guntha   1089.000
9  2.400350e+04    10.00    Grounds   2400.350
```